# Google Chrome is not saving my password

Tags: php, passwords

Chrome won't save user/password (admin/admin)... however Firefox does it.
Is something missing in my code?
Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$valid_passwords = array('admin' => 'admin');
$valid_users = array_keys($valid_passwords); 
$user = $pass = null;

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
{
    $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
}

$validated = (in_array($user, $valid_users)) && ($pass == $valid_passwords[$user]);

if (!$validated)
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Private access"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    exit('Not authorized');
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Have you edited your .htaccess?

Comment: Potential bug in Chrome? https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/EEX4y4mFGOY/3Op4VYKjVD0J

Comment: What do I have to add in .htaccess?